# How to retrieve the input query parameter in Node AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, query-string

I have recently started learning AWS and created a basic Node based lambda as below:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify([event, context, 'Hello from Saurabh Tiwari']),
    };
    return response;
};
```

I have configured the API gateway method request to expect a `name` query parameter as shown below:
[image]

I have also assigned a request validator to the GET call for the API. Having done this the endpoint asks me to necessarily provide a query parameter.

The issue however is that I am unable to receive the query parameter in the lambda function. I expect it to be passed along the `event` parameter. However the event parameter (first parameter in the JSON body) is blank as can be seen in the response object below.

Please suggest how do I retrieve the query param in the lambda.

[image]

Comment: try `event.queryStringParameters[name]`. I think you have to done some configuration wrong thats why APIGateway event which is supposed to be passed as a param is an empty object.

Comment: @vibhor1997a As expected, doing above resulted in `{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined","trace":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:6:58)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:63:25)","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"]}`. The entire event object is blank for whatever reason.

Comment: Have you configured the integration request and set the lambda proxy integration?

Comment: I think not. As I am very new to this, Can you may be suggest how to do the same ?

Comment: You can first click on the `GET` as you can see in your screenshot. There you would find integration request. Click on it then you would see some options including a checkbox `lambda proxy integration`. Check the checkbox and save.

I would recommend you to use a framework like `serverless framework` as they make config easier.

Comment: Thanks @vibhor1997a  Your suggestion worked. Will be glad to accept your answer if you are willing to write one.

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable ‘Lambda Proxy Integration’ under Request Integration tab. Then you can access the query string object as `event.queryStringParameters.name`.